# How can I define and retrieve custom attributes with jQuery's drag and drop events?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

What I want to do is have a list of icons and when each icon is dragged into the droppable area the icons custom data that I have defined is recorded in a list some where.

I would like to assign custom data for each icon such as model number, name, price etc.

Something like...

```
<div class="draggable">
    <img src="icon1.png" width="20" data-price="80" data-name="xxxxxxxxx" data-model="xxxx">
</div>
```

Maybe I'm over complicating things by trying to send the data with the drop event rather than just finding it afterwards by looping through each img element and pulling the attributes with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store few properties you can use data attributes.

Below is the sample implementation of drag and drop with data attributes.
1. On drag: getting the data attributes and storing it as JSON String.
2. On drop: getting the JSON String and parsing it.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("elem", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("data", JSON.stringify(ev.target.dataset));
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData("data")));
  var element = ev.dataTransfer.getData("elem");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(element));

}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69" data-price="80" data-name="xxxxxxxxx" data-model="xxxx">
```

Comment: Thanks for the full example :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event's target object to find the data attributes.

```
var list = [];
$('.draggable').on('dragstop', function(e, ui){
    list.push( $(e.target).data('name') );
});
```